# MATLAB - Saving all base workspace variables into a mat file using uisave

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am trying to allow the user of my software to save all the base workspace variables into a mat* file, however I'm not sure how to accomplish this using 'uisave'.

Is there a better way to do this than calling every single workspace variable manually using `evalin('base', 'var')` and creating a list of strings to input as an argument into uisave?

Comment: Did you try `evalin('base','save fname')`? `save fname` saves all locally visible variables. Executing that statement within the base workspace would save all variables visible there.

Answer (score 0):

The function `save` will do it:

```
save('filename.mat')
```

You also may save one or several variables with the same function:

```
save('filename.mat', 'variable1', 'variable2')
```